# Como acessar um metodo dentro de um array de objeto?

Tags: java, array

Quando tento acessar a variavel ValorDebitado dentro da classe relação de débitos acontece o erro:
"Cannot invoke "cartao.Item.setValorDebitado(double)" because "this.relacaoDeDebitos[this.compra]" is null"

Classe principal:

```
package cartao;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cartão {
     static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conta c1 = new Conta();
        c1.setCompra(0);
        System.out.println("Defina a senha do cartão: ");
        criarSenha(c1);
    }
    
    static void criarSenha(Conta c1) {
        c1.setSenha(scn.nextInt());
        menu(c1);
    }

static void menu(Conta c1) {
    int loop = 0;
    while(loop < 1) {
    
        System.out.println("\n---Tabela---");
        System.out.println("1 - Debitar");
        System.out.println("2 - Gerar faturas");
        
        int opt = scn.nextInt();
        
       
        switch(opt) {
        case 1:
            boolean a = debitar(c1);  
            if(a == true) {
                System.out.println("Débito realizado com sucesso!"); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Falha ao realizar débito.");
            }
            
            break;
        } 
    }
}
    
static boolean debitar(Conta c1) {
    
    System.out.println("\nInsira a sua senha: ");
        if(c1.getSenha() != scn.nextInt()) {
            return false;
        }
        
            System.out.println("\nInsira o valor a ser debitado: ");
            c1.setValorDebito(scn.nextDouble(), 0);
            
            int compra;
            
            System.out.println("\nInsira o nome do estabelecimento: ");
            compra = c1.getCompra();
            c1.setLocalDebitado(scn.next(), compra);
            compra++;
            c1.setCompra(compra);
            
            return true;

}

}
```

Classe conta:

```
public class Conta {
  private int senha;
  private double saldo;
  private Item[] relacaoDeDebitos = new Item[10];    
  private int compra;
  
  public double getSaldo() {
      return saldo;
  }
  
  public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
      if(saldo > 0) {
          this.saldo = saldo;
      }
  }
  
  public int getCompra() {
      return compra;
  }
  
  public void setCompra(int compra) {
      this.compra = compra;
  }
  
  public int getSenha() {
      return senha;
  }
  
  public void setSenha(int senha) {
      if (senha > 0 && senha <= 9999)
      this.senha = senha;
  }

  public double getValorDebitado(int compra) {
      return relacaoDeDebitos[compra].getValorDebito();
  }
  
  public void setValorDebito(double valorDebito, int compra) {
      this.relacaoDeDebitos[compra].setValorDebito(valorDebito);
  }
  
  public String getLocalDebitado(int compra) {
      return relacaoDeDebitos[compra].getLocalDebito();
  }
  
  public void setLocalDebitado(String localDebitado, int compra) {
      this.relacaoDeDebitos[compra].setLocalDebito(localDebitado);
  }

  
}
```

Classe relação de debitos:

```
public class Item {
   private String LocalDebitado;
   private double ValorDebitado;
   
   public String getLocalDebito() {
       return LocalDebitado;
   }
   
   public void setLocalDebito(String LocalDebitado) {
       this.LocalDebitado = LocalDebitado;
   }
   
   public double getValorDebito() {
       return ValorDebitado;
   }
   
   public void setValorDebito(double ValorDebitado) {
       this.ValorDebitado = ValorDebitado;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vc não está declarando o parametro para compra no setLocalDebitado dentro da classe Conta. Tem apenas um String LocalDebitado. Então quando ele executa o compra que tem dentro da função não aponta para lugar nenhum. null. Arruma isso e ve se funciona e avisa aqui depois.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Editei o código passando o compra como parâmetro, mas o mesmo erro continua acontecendo